# Separate sure vent blocking new sink? Can it be moved?

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, kitchen-sink

We were installing a new sink from our old 5 inch sink and got halted when we realized it wouldn’t fit because of a sure vent. Of course we had no idea what it was and googled but now we are even more confused. We see sure vent installations online that connect to the p trap. Our vent is by itself. We want to install a new sure vent and close off the old vent part that’s blocking the sink but don’t know if that’s a even doable. Can the top sure vent be closed and we use one   On our main line? [image: here is a pic of our setup. Both lines come horizontally out the wall. The sure vent is the one on top,plumbing on bottom.]

Comment: are you certain that it is a sure vent? ... it is horizontal

Comment: What is the orientation of the photo? Is the white cloth on the right side of the photo actually the bottom? So the threaded open end of the elbow actually faces up? If so, the pipe with the threaded elbow goes into the wall and meets the same vertical pipe the drain goes into, venting above it as required.